# What is =~ operator in elixir

Tags: elixir

From the [documentation](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/sigils.html) I understand how `=~` operator works to match regex, but I don't understand the general use of this operator.

For example, what does `"foo" =~ "foo"` mean? 
How is it different from `"foo" == "foo"`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's not documented on that page, but it's documented in [`Kernel.=~/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#=%7E/2) that when the RHS is a string, `=~` checks if LHS contains RHS:

```
iex(1)> "foo" =~ "f"
true
iex(2)> "foo" =~ "o"
true
```

It does not implicitly convert RHS to regex:

```
iex(3)> "foo" =~ "."
false
```

If RHS is a regular expression, returns true if left matches right:

```
iex(4)> "abcd" =~ ~r/e/
false
```

Comment: I haven't seen that there was a more complete documentation, thanks.